# Couldn't Calculate Price and Qty on table using Php Ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am creating a ecommerce site for my final year project.while I am creating a project I ran in to the problem with product shall be able add the  card but when I view the card product shown which I added into the card.my problem is if the give qty it will auto calculation  and display result on the total textbox.and final totel show display below. I attached image below what i tried so far. But couldn’t calculate the total and final total.
**Display the Products**
[image]

```
<script>
getProducts();

    function getProducts() {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'all_cart.php',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) {
                data.forEach(function(element) {
                    var id = element.id;
                    var product_name = element.product_name;
                    var price = element.price;
                   $('#mytable tbody').after
                   (
                        '<tr> ' +
                        '<td>' + id + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + product_name + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + price + '</td>' +
                        "<input type='hidden' name='price' value='" + price + "'>" +
                        '<td>' + "<input type = 'text' id='qty' name='qty'/>" + '</td>' +
                        '<td>' + "<input type = 'text' id='amount'/>" + '</td>' +
                        '</tr>');
                  });
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

**Auto calcaltion the price * qty**

```
$(function() {
    $("#price, #qty").on("keydown keyup click", qty);
    function qty() {
        var sum = (
        Number($("#price").val()) * Number($("#qty").val())
        );

        $('#amount').val(sum);
        console.log(sum);
    }
});
```

Comment: 1. multiple same `id` will not work when you are going to use them in jquery, so convert each `id` to `class`.2.you have to use `$(this)` to address current changed input box

Comment: can you write the code it is easy to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont should append multiple elements with same ID in a page

Can you try

```
function getProducts() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
               $('#mytable tbody').after
               (
                    '<tr> ' +
                    '<td>' + id + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + product_name + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + price + '</td>' +
                    "<input type='hidden' name='price' class='price' value='" + price + "'>" +
                    '<td>' + "<input type = 'text' class='qty' name='qty'/>" + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + "<input type = 'text' class='amount'/>" + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>');
              });
        },
        error: function(xhr, status, error) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}


$(function() {
  $(".price, .qty").on("keydown keyup click", function () {
    var price = $(this).parents('tr').find('.price');
    var qty= $(this).parents('tr').find('.qty');
    var sum = (
    Number($(price).val()) * Number($(qty).val())
    );
    $(this).parents('tr').find('.amount').val(sum);
        calculateAmount();
  });
  function calculateAmount() {
       var total = 0;
       $('.amount').each(function(e){
          total += Number($(this).val());      
       });
       $('#total-amount').text(total);
  }
});
```

This is a demo: https://codepen.io/phuongnm153/pen/bymYOQ

Comment: i just copy and paste the code in to my project it doen't work sir. if i enter the qty total not displyed

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: tr is not defined i got the error on console sir

Comment: Sorry my mistake in `$(this).parents('tr')`

Comment: NaN displayed at the console and values is not diplayed on the total textbox

Comment: working sir thanks for your help then how to calculating final total please tell me

Comment: working well sir final total want to display below of table can you help me sir

Comment: @NisaYathu I added more `function calculateAmount()` folow your expected. Can you see my demo

Answer (score 0):

When you get **$("#price").val()** and **$("#qty").val()** in jQuery but you have many $("#price") & $("#qty") duplicate. You should be run this in console.
I hope it's helpful for you